# Performance implications of using Async Hooks

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, rpc, nodejs-server, async-hooks

I'm the author of a Node.js library and I want to use [Async Hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html) to improve DX. But I'm worried about performance.

I've read stories saying that everything is fine, as well as stories where performance was a blocker.

In theory, asynchronicity should only happen for IO operations and performance penality should be pretty much ~0. (As IO operations are several orders of magnitude more expensive than running JS code.)

But, in practice, does running extra JS on each async call induces a non-negligible performance degradation?

What is your experience with the performance of async hooks?

### Use Case

The concrete use case is [Wildcard API](https://github.com/reframejs/wildcard-api) where I'm using Async Hooks which enables wonderful ergonomics for Wildcard users:

```js
const { server } = require("@wildcard-api/server");
const { context } = require("@wildcard-api/context");
const db = require("./path/to/db");

// Server endpoint for user login
server.login = async (userEmail, password) => {
  if (!checkCredentials(userEmail, password)) {
    return { wrongCredentials: true };
  }
  const { userId, userName } = await db.getUser(userEmail);
  // Context modifications are persisted. (Under the hood,
  // Wildcard uses Cookies to persist the context.)
  context.user = {
    userId,
    userName,
  };
};

// Server endpoint to get the to-do list of the logged-in user.
server.getTodoList = async () => {
  // `context.userId` is available here!
  const { userId } = context;
  if (!userId) {
    return { notLoggedIn: true };
  }
  const todos = await db.getTodoList(userId);
  return todos;
};

// The neat thing here is that the following also works:

<div>
  {/*              ...                  */}
  {/* Somewhere deep in a React tree... */}
  {/*              ...                  */}
  <Header>
    {
      // The Wildcard `context` is availble here!
      // Thanks to async hooks, Wildcard knows to which
      // HTTP request `context` belongs too. (While doing SSR.)
      context.userId ? <SignIn /> : <Logout />
    }
  </Header>;
</div>;
```

Thanks to Async Hooks, the Wildcard `context` is availble anywhere(!) within the lifecycle of the HTTP request.

Wildcard's async hook [code is small](https://github.com/reframejs/wildcard-api/blob/9ac10fcd8a673515c854a143362c9ac4fced6100/src/server/context/async-hook-management.ts#L42-L84) but runs for *each* async call happening whithin the context of an HTTP request.

The main danger here are memory leaks but Wildcard's test suit is checking that there are no memory leaks.

Comment: Discussion about perfromance with the author of AsyncLocalStorage: https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/kxvakk/performance_implications_of_using_async_hooks/

Comment: There are definitely some impact to performance as there is more function call to keep track of all the `asyncId`

However, I find that the performance impact is negligible to be honest, as you will need another way of managing `context`, which would just about the same.

Here is my repo on some micro-test
https://github.com/Darkripper214/ALS-CLS-Benchmark

The performance of `AsyncLocalStorage` is really good